# Looping a directory to process multiple XML files

Tags: c#, sql, xml, database

I have a client application that locates a file based on a static path and processes it accordingly:

```
string filepath = @"C:\Users\NChamber\Desktop\package\1002423A_attachments.xml";
byte[] byteArray = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filepath);
channel.UploadTransaction(filepath, 27, byteArray);
```

This is working fine for single file updates, but what I need is to scan the entire directory for all files ending "*.xml" and process them all.

So far I have tried this to little success:

```
string path = @"C:\Users\NChamber\Desktop\package\";

foreach (string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, "*.xml"))
{
    byte[] byteArray = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path);
    channel.UploadTransaction(path, 27, byteArray);
}
```

Any suggestions would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: What does "little success" mean? What problem do you have?

Comment: out of interest, what class is `channel`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you aren't actually doing anything with the `file` within your foreach loop, you're just passing in `path` on each iteration.

```
foreach (string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, "*.xml"))
{
    byte[] byteArray = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path);
    channel.UploadTransaction(file, 27, byteArray);
}
```

I suspect you mean: `System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(file);` e.g:

```
foreach (string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, "*.xml"))
{
    byte[] byteArray = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(file);
    channel.UploadTransaction(file, 27, byteArray);
}
```

And then: `channel.UploadTransaction(file, 27, byteArray);`

Comment: `GetFiles` has no benefit over `EnumerateFiles` unless you especially need an array instead of a sequence. In many cases it is an inferior choice.

Comment: Edited. I don't think the issue is with `EnumerateFiles`. He's passing in the path to `ReadAllBytes/UploadTransaction` which is obviously incorrect, my answer already has this correction in though so hardly worth the -1...

Comment: Your first line is "What you want is `Directory.GetFiles`" which is a red herring and will infact decrease the overall performance of the code. You had fixed the error in the code but since you had not made that clear the OP could implement your change and think that `GetFiles` had helped. Therefore, I think it is good idea to clear this up so it does not dilute the good of the answer. After all, what else are down votes for?

Comment: @Jodrell No problem, jumped the gun a bit as I'm not familiar with `EnumerateFiles()`. In the interest of learning, why would `GetFiles` it decrease the overall performance? (genuine question). I will edit out my original comments to avoid confusion :)

Comment: I've taken the liberty of editing your answer, I think this adds clarity, I hope you agree.

Comment: `EnumerateFiles` will yield each file as it finds it, `GetFiles` builds an array, then returns it. This means that `EnumerateFiles` will start returning data sooner and doesen't have the overhead of array creation. If there are few files this will make almost no difference but for many files could be siginificant. If the processing of the file collection could effect sibling files the use of `GetFiles` may be required, since it effectively snapshots the results before processing begins.

Comment: Great explanation thanks. I just set up a benchmark test over 1000000 iterations and `Enumerate files` completes in: 24570.23 ns on average, whereas `GetFiles` completed in: 112604.42 ns which would back up your claims.

Comment: Spot on, many thanks for the help. Amazing how easy it is to skim over something like that! And thanks for all the follow up comments from the both of you, very useful learning.

Answer (score 2):

Try with this:

```
foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.xml"))
{
byte[] byteArray = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(file);
channel.UploadTransaction(file, 27, byteArray);                        
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A minor error on the loop, you need to call `ReadAllBytes` with `file` instead of `path`:

```
byte[] byteArray = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(file);
```